# Can two waves have the same amplitude but different frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

If the question above is true, how is that possible?

Comment: I suppose this question is trivially true.  Can you provide more details about what you are thinking and in what context?

Comment: I have read, that the higher the frequency the lower the amplitude. But at the same time I have heard it is possible for two different Frequencies to have the same Amplitude, how is that then possible? Like lets take for example 1 Mhz and 1 Ghz.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In most cases, there's absolutely no correlation between frequency and amplitude. What's the context of your question, that you might assume that there is?

Comment: Get a piece of string. Wiggle your hand up and down the same distance each time. And change the speed at which you do it. you have made 2 waves of same amplitude with different frequency

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse they can.

What makes you think that they can't?

High frequency waves do not necessarily  have more energy than lower frequency waves also.

$f = A\cos(\omega_{1} t)$

$f= Acos(\omega_{2} t)$

These waves have the same amplitude but different frequency.

For 2 EM waves with the same amplitude and different frequency, below resonance: It is true that the oscillation amplitude of an electron where the wave is incident it , is dependant on the frequency of the incoming wave  and thus the emmited waves amplitude is dependant on the frequency of the incident wave.

That is not to say that the amplitude of the wave is dependant on the frequency in general